# How do I pass values between scopes inside the same View in Swift?

Tags: swift, swiftui, scope

I want to make decisions based on what user selects but I learned that I cannot put logic related codes inside View. Now, how do I use the variable of one scope in another?

In the given code, user gets to select the tip amount he wants to provide to the server. I want to display a message based on the tip the waiter receives. How do I use the variable `self.tipPercentages[0]` from section-1 in  section-2 of the code?

Thank you

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var tipPercentage = 2
    
    @State var tipPercentages = [10, 15, 20, 25]
    @State var tipSelected = 0

    @State var if_10 = "okay, thanks"]
    @State var if_20 = "Wow, thank you!"


    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("How much tip do you want to leave?")) {      #<------ section1
                    Picker("Tip Percentage", selection: $tipPercentage) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< tipPercentages.count) {
                            Text("\(self.tipPercentages[$0])%")
                            tip_selected = self.tipPercentages[0]  #<--- A varibale I want to use later
                        }
                    }
                    .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                }
                
                Section(header: Text("You decide to reward your server with [tip_selected %] tip")) {   #<------ section2
                    Text("[Thank you message]")
                }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `selection` parameter of `Picker` will do the work of storing the tip amount for you -- there's no need for the `tipSelected =` line of imperative code.

Then, unless you're planning on mutating them somewhere, the `if_10` and `if_20` don't really need to be `@State` variables.

Here's one possible solution:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var tipPercentages = [10, 15, 20, 25]
    @State var tipSelected = 0

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("How much tip do you want to leave?")) {
                    Picker("Tip Percentage", selection: $tipSelected) {
                        ForEach(tipPercentages, id: \.self) { tip in
                            Text("\(tip)%")
                        }
                    }
                    .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                }
                
                if tipSelected > 0 {
                    Section(header: Text("You decide to reward your server with \(tipSelected) tip")) {
                        Text(tipSelected < 20 ? "okay, thanks" : "Wow, thank you!")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you wanted to start with a `20%` tip, you could assign `20` to `tipSelected` for its initial value instead of `0`.

Comment: It provides a way for the `ForEach` to differentiate elements in the event that the collection doesn't conform to `Identifiable` (which `Int` does not). In this case, it's saying "just use the `Int` value itself as an `id`". Also, since this is in a `Picker`, it's making sure that the `Int` value is what is used for the `selection` property -- that's why `tipSelected` gets the correct value.